# Operator overloading functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am stuck with regards to the 2 non-member, 2 non-friend multiplication and the addition of the operator overloading functions. I am unsure of how to do it. Could someone please assist in helping me to resolve this? Refer to my codes below. Thank you in advance!

Compiler output:

```
Point.cpp:208:19: error: passing ‘const CS170::Point’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

    return other + value;
                   ^~~~~

Point.cpp: In function ‘CS170::Point CS170::

operator*(double, const CS170::Point&)’:

Point.cpp:215:10: error: ‘double CS170::Point::x’ is private within this context

   result.x = value * x;
          ^

Point.cpp:215:22: error: ‘x’ was not declared in this scope

   result.x = value * x;
                      ^
Point.cpp:216:10: error: ‘double CS170::Point::y’ is private within this context

   result.y =  value * y;
          ^

Point.cpp:216:23: error: ‘y’ was not declared in this scope
   result.y =  value * y;
```

Point.h

```
  #include <iostream> // istream, ostream

  namespace CS1100
{
  class Point
  {
   public:
  // Point(double X, double Y);    // Constructors (2)
  explicit Point(double x, double y); 

   Point();

   Point operator+(const Point& other)const ;

   Point& operator+(double value);


   Point operator*(double value) ;

   Point operator%(double value);


   Point operator-(const Point& other)const ;

   Point operator-(double value);

   Point operator^(const Point& other);

   Point operator+=(double value);
   Point& operator+=(const Point& other) ;

   Point& operator++();
   Point operator++(int); 

   Point& operator--(); 
   Point operator--(int); 

   Point& operator-();


        // Overloaded operators (14 member functions)
   friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Point &point );
    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, Point &point );

    // Overloaded operators (2 friend functions)

private:
  double x; // The x-coordinate of a Point
  double y; // The y-coordinate of a Point

    // Helper functions
  double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) const;
  double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) const;
 };

 // Point& Add(const Point& other); // Overloaded operators (2 non-member, non-friend functions)
    // Point& Multiply(const Point& other);
    Point operator+( double value, const Point& other );
    Point operator-( double value, const Point& other );
```

My source code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 2 non-members, non-friends (operators)


double operator+( double value, const Point& other ) 
{
     return other + value;
}   

double operator*( double value, const Point& other ) 
{

    Point result;
    result.x = value * x;
    result.y =  value * y;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the discussion to the question, the problem is not really the operators themselves, but the number of allowed member functions being limited – and you already have exceeded this limit.

However, you have quite a number of functions that don't need to be members, for instance:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point operator+(const Point& other) const
    {
        return Point(x + other.x, y + other.y);
    }
};
```

Make free functions from all these:

```
class Point { /*...*/ };

Point operator+(Point const& l, Point const& r)
{
    return Point(l.getX() + r.getX(), l.getY() + r.getY());
}
```

Having moved out all these operators like the one shown above, you get away far enough from the limit so that you can introduce the needed getters:

```
class Point
{
public:
    double getX() { return x; };
    double getY() { return y; };
};
```

If you are willing to rename the member variables, e. g. by adding a prefix, you can follow another pattern:

```
class Point
{
    double m_x, m_y;
public:
    double x() { return m_x; };
    double y() { return m_y; };

    void x(double v) { m_x = v; }; // the corresponding setter
                                   // (for illustration, you might not need it)
};
```

This latter pattern is quite common, too. Advantage is being shorter for skipping the explicit `get` or `set` prefix, disadvantage is exactly losing this explicitness... Decide you, which one you prefer. More important than personal preference is consistency, though, so if there's e. g. a company's convention or common practice, follow that one...

Some of your operators will need to remain members, though, these are all those that *modify* the current object:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point& operator+=(const Point& other) /* const */ // NEEDS to be non-const
    {
        x += other.x;
        y += other.y;
        return *this; // <- very good hint to spot the ones needing to stay members
    }
};
```

If you have a public *copy* constructor, you can re-use the `operator+=` for defining the `operator+`:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(Point const& other) : Point(other.x, other.y) { }
};

Point operator+(Point const& x, Point const& y)
{
    Point r(x); // or Point(x.x(), x.y()), if you lack such constructor)
    r += y;
    return r;
}
```

Actually, you can even spare the explicit copy by accepting one of the parameters by value:

```
Point operator+(Point x, Point const& y)
//                    ^ no reference
{
    return x += y;
}
```

The latter rather for illustration, I'd prefer the two references in given case to keep the symmetry of the interface...